# How to add a PHP method to a third party class without editing the third party class?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, traits

I am using a third party library that has a base class "Exchange".  I would like to add my own public method to the base class without editing the base class (hence surviving an upgrade).  I have done some reading on inheritance but can only think of the following 3 ways to achieve this:

1. Paste my method directly into "Exchange"
2. Create a trait with my method and add "use MyMethod()" into "Exchange"
3. Rename "Exchange" to "oldExchange" then create a new class that "extends Exchange" with my method within it.

Obviously all 3 solutions require editing the third party code which means it will not survive a code update.

I am a beginner, so if you do have a solution, I would appreciate a verbose answer, with skeleton code if required.

Thank you.

EDIT:  Based on the responses I realised I have left out a very important constraint.  The base class is not used by my code directly. My code uses the child classes that extend "Exchange" and are also part of the same third party package, so I would have to edit each one of those to use an extended Exchange. The child classes are all part of the same package as the parent class, so the problem of overwriting on updates remains.

Comment: Create a class called `MyExchange` that extends `Exchange` and implements your method. Then you use `MyExchange` instead. That wouldn't require you to modify the base library at all.

Comment: Can you paste the signature of the existing function? ie the line where the function is declared in the class?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson apologies but I forgot to add one more pertinent restriction.  The base class is not used by my code directly.  My code uses the child classes that extend "Exchange", so I would have to edit each one of those to use "MyExchange".  The child classes are all part of the same package as the parent class.

Comment: @Scuzzy I don't follow.  I haven't yet incorporated MyFunction into the parent class

Comment: Do you want to be able to use your own method on all the child classes? Otherwise, just do as suggested above but for the child class instead. `MyChildClass extends ChildClass` and use `MyChildClass` instead. It's still the same solution.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I do want to be able to use my method in all the child classes, hence why I wish to target the parent class.

Comment: Well... you can't. You will need to extend all the child classes you use. Create a trait with your method and simply extend the child classes and add the trait to them. Then you use your classes instead.

Comment: @Viktorius Oh so you don't want to replace any of the existing functions? You just want to add to it or use the existing class in your class?

Comment: Yes, I am simply adding a new public method to the parent class.  My script will ultimately be instantiating the child classes derived from the parent class.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson.  If I have 100 child classes to extend, is there a way of using a loop to do it dynamically... eval()??

Answer (score 2):

You should inherit from `Exchange` and add your public/custom code to your custom class.

E.g.: CustomExchage extends Exchange.

**Update:**
Even if you need to use a third party child class: the solution remains the same. Extend from that child class (or generally from the most specific class)

This may prevent you from library updates. Every time, the library's maintainer updates the code, you have to add your custom code back to `Exchange` class. Thinking about automated deployments: you will probably not realize, when there are updates, that can leave to broken code for your application.

A stronger reason for extending: your custom code may not belong to a base class (in simple words).

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends on the structure of exchange(everything might be private and not accessible) but you could extend the class.

```
class YourExchange extends Exchange {
    public function yourMethod() {}
}
```

You can then use your class instead of Exchange.

Again it might need a bit more duplicated depending on whats private/protected/public or of Exchange is final.

An example is if Exchange has `private function fooBar()` which your new method might want to access but can not because `private`. So saying 'oh yeah just extend the class' might not be as straight forward as people make out.

[Here is an 3v4l example](https://3v4l.org/ETi27)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best choice is the 3rd solution. What you can do is to create your base class that extend Exchange like so:

```
class MyExchange extends Exchange {
  public function myMethod () {

  }
}
```

Then use this class as parent to your own classes like so:

```
class MyChildExchange extends MyExchange {
  //implement your method here
  public function myOtherMethod() {
    // call parent function
    $this->myMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP does not allow you to add method to a class at runtime, you should edit the Exchange class or make your own one inherited from Exchange class.